# How to overwrite an ArrayList without invoking garbage collection

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection, immutability

Is there any way to do the following without either invoking garbage collection or increasing heap size to avoid eventual GC?

```
List<Long> someList = new ArrayList<Long>();
someList.add(1l);
someList = new ArrayList<Long>(); //Will this cause GC of the old `someList`?
```

So what I'm asking is if the original `ArrayList` will get deleted (and eventually GCd)? If so, how do I remedy this such that I can overwrite the original list without GCing?

Comment: Yes, the original list will get deleted and garbage collected.  But, that's not what the title of your question asks.  Was there something else you needed to know?  Incidentally, for readability, please use a capital L for long literals - `1L` won't get confused with eleven.

Comment: ArrayList is not immutable. Indeed you are modifying it at second line.

Comment: you can just use `list.clear()` method to clear all node in it!

Comment: In this particular case if you use `clear()` on `someList` the list object and its element (Long(1)) will not be eligible for GC because Long objects that ware result of autoboxing long values in range `[-128; 127]` are cached by JVM. But if you would `add(1234)` instead this autoboxed Long object would become eligible for garbage collection because there is no reference to it anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ArrayList.clear();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) instead of creating new ArrayList

```
someList.clear();
```

Comment: This way the values (one Long in the example) will be GCd but not the list.

Answer (score 2):

The older `ArrayList` will become eligible for garbage collection on line 3, provided there is no other reference pointing to it, as it seems is the case here. However, it isn't guaranteed to be GCed right away.

If you want to avoid extra creation of the `ArrayList`, you can simply clear it by using `List#clear()` method:

```
someList.clear();
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the object mutable so that I overwrite the original arraylist instead of GCing and then replacing?

Comment: Why are you so afraid of GC? What is aour real problem?

Comment: assign it to a new variable? `List<Long> tmp = someList; someList = new ArrayList<>();` now tmp will hold your old someList with a strong reference and therefore will prevent the GC form collecting it

Comment: @user2763361 I'm afraid, I'm not really getting your issue. What is bothering you. What are you actually trying to avoid?

Comment: It should be noted that while `someList.clear()` doesn't make `someList` eligible for GC, this will in most cases just make the situation worse, since now all references in the list will be set to `null` explicitly to allow the objects to be garbage collected (have a look at the source of `ArrayList.clear()`).

Comment: @Axel it is unclear if the list itself should not get GCed or the content of the list

Comment: @RomanVottner: it is unclear what the OP wants to achieve. Why would anyone want an object not to get GCed if he will not use the object again?

Comment: @Axel maybe for caching reasons to speed up future invocations? Imagine you place a `Class<?>` object somewhere and it would be the last strong reference to this object (next to the one the ClassLoader contains). If this strong reference gets lost the class definition as well as the ClassLoader would get eligible for GC (assuming the ClassLoader only loaded that class). On new invocations of instantiations of that class the class definition has to be loaded from somewhere again instead of using the old cached definition - just a simple case, not sure if this matches with the OPs intention

Answer (score 0):

I assume by your question you want to keep a reference to the old list (and also its content, otherwise whats the point)?

If so then just add a reference to it before reassigning:

```
List<Long> someList = new ArrayList<Long>();
someList.add(1L);
List<Long> oldList = someList;
someList = new ArrayList<Long>();
```